# How to get values from posted html form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html forms and I am posting input data from one html form to another html form.I want to retrieve values of variables that was posted using form 1 on the form 2.

```
<form name ="form1" id ="form1" method ="post" action = "form2.html>
   <input id ="sendToForm2" type ="hidden" value ="send this to form2"/>
</form>
```

My question is how to get the value of the hidden variable sendToForm2 on form 2 once it is posted from form 1 to form 2 using javascript.

Comment: You need to use something like PHP for this I guess?.

Comment: Its simple html and javscript. I am not aware about php.

Comment: Which server technology (ASP.NET, PHP etc.) do you use?

Comment: Are both forms on the same page?

Comment: What are you doing with the posted data?

Comment: Just do not use POST but GET, you'll need to parse URL but you'll have them. For POST method you need some sort of server side code.

Comment: No. Both are on different html pages. form1 on form1.html and similarly form2 on form2.html.

Comment: @Adriano is correct, if you use get, it will post the values as a query string.

Comment: Explanation: with POST data will be sent through headers but a plain HTML page does not have access to that, it has only its own HTML code and URL.

Comment: You could also use a Cookie.

Comment: What is your form2.HTML for ? And what do your intend doing generally so that you are guided in the right part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `POST` method because with a *plain* HTML page you do not have HTTP headers but HTML page code itself and URL (with query string).

What you can do is to use `GET` instead of `POST` then parse query string to extract them:

```
<form name ="form1" id ="form1" method ="GET" action = "form2.html>
   <input id ="sendToForm2" type ="hidden" value ="send this to form2"/>
</form>
```

Then in your `form2.html` you can use this function (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) on SO) to parse query string:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Now (let me use jQuery) you can access them with this:

```
<form ...>
   <input id ="sentFromForm1" type ="hidden" value =""/>
</form>

</script>
    $("#sentFromForm1").val(getParameterByName("sendToForm2"));
</script>
```